# Grub not showing at boot

Tags: grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 along side of Win8 on a separate harddisk. But it is not showing the grub menu at boot time, instead it boots to Win8 directly. Can anyone help me?

Secure boot is disabled. Here is my [boot-repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rDgGzGBv8S/).

Comment: Improve your question with more details (uefi ? , partition method ,etc)

Comment: Both Windows & Ubuntu are in UEFI boot mode as boot files are in ESP - efi system partition. Details are all in Summary Report from Boot-Repair. But you have an HP, and it violates UEFI standard. Can you manually boot from UEFI boot menu either Ubuntu entry or hard drive entry? If you want Ubuntu as default boot, you will need a work around. Boot-Repair already has copied shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi as fallback or hard drive boot. You may be able to set it as default. See: Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: Thanks for your help.I can manually boot from uefi boot menu .I solved the problem by running this command in windows cmd -   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi and then in ubuntu i ran sudo update-grub.

Comment: Just out of interest how many menu entries on grub2 do you have starting with 'Windows' or 'EFI/'? I counted 15. Is that still the situation?

Comment: yeah,there is 15 menu entries on grub2.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of obvious, but seeing as you haven't mentioned it in your post could you make sure your boot priority is correct in the BIOS?

Comment: That's part of your problem. You should have 1 entry for Ubuntu, 1 for Ubuntu advanced options, 1 for Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2), and 1 for System Setup (BIOS). The other entries are superfluous to requirements.